# Find the earliest record in each group by month

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
Month  Name  Revenue   EARLY_MIN
Jan     A     100        ?
Jan     A      50        ?
Feb     A      30        ?
```

For each 'Name', I want to pick the earliest record (Jan). If  it returns more than one row, I will pick the record with min. Revenue. So 50 in this case. And I will create a column EARLY_MIN=1 for this record. So in this example, the second row with have EARLY_MIN=1, other rows will have EARLY_MIN=0.

How can I do this in pandas with min. number of steps?

Comment: Do you have all twelve months in your data?

Comment: Yes...goes from Nov one year to Oct next year..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using python's `calendar` stdlib, you can convert "Months" to a numeric value. This makes it easy for us to order rows based on the "Month" value.

```
import calendar

mapping = {calendar.month_abbr[k]: k for k in range(1, 13)}
u = df.assign(Month=df.Month.map(mapping))
u

   Month Name  Revenue EARLY_MIN
0      1    A      100         ?
1      1    A       50         ?
2      2    A       30         ?
```

Now, you can use `groupby` and `idxmin`, or something similar.

```
idx = (u['Revenue'].mask(u.groupby('Name').Month.transform('min') != u['Month'])
                   .groupby(u.Name)
                   .idxmin()
                   .values)
df.loc[idx, 'EARLY_MIN'] = 1
df

  Month Name  Revenue EARLY_MIN
0   Jan    A      100         ?
1   Jan    A       50         1
2   Feb    A       30         ?
```

Comment: @Vaishali It depends on whether the minimum revenue is in the first row or not, I'm guessing. I am finding the idxmin of the revenue.

Comment: @Vaishali just checked it. Since this groups on "Name", the index will have the labels of "Name" (in this case, "A"), so not very helpful. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

By using the same setting up with Vaishali

```
#df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Month, format='%b').dt.month

df['EARLY_MIN']=(~df.sort_values(['Month','Revenue']).duplicated('Name',keep='first')).astype(int)
df
Out[1006]: 
   Month Name  Revenue  EARLY_MIN
0      1    A      100          0
1      1    A       50          1
2      2    A       30          0
```